# Discord : message.content.split

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have problem in this code. After I write this code I receive this error :

```
  File "bot.py", line 90, in on_message:
    if message.content.split("{}".format(blacklist))[1].strip():
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
blacklist = ['test1','test2']
if message.content.split("{}".format(blacklist))[1].strip():
    embed=discord.Embed(title=":no_entry_sign: Blacklisted", description="If you're an idiot at least stop flagging")
    embed.set_footer(text="If you'd like to appeal to be whitelisted please contact, Adryan#1677")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
    await client.delete_message(message)
```

Comment: Hello ! Can you edit your post and write the error message instead of giving an image link?

Comment: Brought error message image inline

Comment: What do you expect that `if` statement to check?

Answer (score 0):

`message.content.split("{}".format(blacklist))` isn't guaranteed to return a list with more than one item.

```
"abc".split("d") # returns ['abc']
"abcd".split("d") # returns ['abc', '']
if "abc".split("d")[1]:
    print("foo") # will never be reached since Python IndexErrors on evaluating the if condition
```

Since you don't ensure that the list has more than one element and immediately go to getting the item at index one, whenever `.split` gives you a one-item long list, you get an `IndexError`.

If you want to test if `split` actually returned a list longer than one item, you would be best served by `len(message.content.split(separator)) > 1`.